# meta field search too restrictive in pre_get_post() for custom search

Tags: search, post-meta, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to figure out how to loosen up a custom meta field matching string search in a custom search.

Basically, if the meta field of a custom post has "Whistler Bike Park, Canada" and I enter that, I will get the post returned in the search.  But if I enter just "Whistler", then I get nothing.

The key line I believe needs editing looks like this:

```
$where .= " OR (( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$meta_key' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '$meta_value' ))";
```

Here is the full pre_get_post() hook.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'site_search_query');
function site_search_query( $query ) 
{
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

        if ( $query->is_search ) :

            // if just a normal search and no in spanish - return 
            // we need to make exception for normal search and is spanish for spanish titles
            // since those are meta values
            if( ( count($_GET) == 1 ) && ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != "es" ) )
                return;

            $s = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $_GET['s'] ); // sanitize and get search string;

            unset( $_GET['s'] );
            $params = array();

            foreach( $_GET as $key => $param ) :

                $params[$key] = preg_replace( "/[^a-z0-9.]+/i", "", $param );

            endforeach;

            $meta_queries = array();

            foreach( $params as $param ) :

                switch( $param ) :

                    case 'org':
                        $param = 'organization';
                    break;

                    case 'desc':
                        $param = 'basic_info_long_description_in_english';
                    break;

                endswitch;

                $args = array(
                        'key' => $param,
                        'value' => $s,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    );

                array_push( $meta_queries, $args );

            endforeach;

            $query->set( 'post_type', 'project' );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array( $args ) );

            /**
             *  Apparently this is a hack to allow for search by post meta in meta_query for pre_get_post $query->set()
             *  See: http://wpthemetutorial.com/2014/07/17/using-pre_get_posts-meta_query/
             *  this is done as an anonymous function so we can pass it local vars

             *  @param string
             *  @param complex array
             *  @param function
             *  @return string
             */
            $custom_filter = function( $where = '' ) use( $meta_queries, $custom_filter ) 
            {

                global $wpdb;

                foreach( $meta_queries as $meta_query ) :

                    $meta_key = $meta_query['key'];
                    $meta_value = $meta_query['value'];

                    // too restrictive
                    $where .= " OR (( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$meta_key' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '$meta_value' ))";

                    // too loose
                    //$where .= " OR (( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$meta_key' ))";

                endforeach;

                remove_filter( 'posts_where', $custom_filter );

                return $where;

            };

            add_filter( 'posts_where', $custom_filter );

        endif; // is_search

    endif; // is not admin && is main query

} // site_search_query
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have an answer - it was how the SQL statement was setup.

```
$where .= " OR (( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$meta_key' AND (UPPER($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value) LIKE '%$meta_value%') ))";
```

Now is the field has the string "Whistler Bike Park, Canada" but the user only searches for "Whistler", I get the post/s returned that I expect.